# how to get proper date In arabic culture language instead of 01/01/0001 at controller side in asp.net mvc c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I am working with english and arabic culture in Asp.Net MVC. Where I need to fill form in both language. So when I select english culture and fill form with date then I am getting proper date in controller side and data are save successfully in database. While I select arabic culture and select date from datepicker then on controller side I am getting wrong date like `01/01/0001`. I don't know from where date is going to change. 
How can I make it working ?

Model Side :

```
public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
```

View Side :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.BirthDate, new { @type = "text", @class = "form-control form-control-sm birth_date" } )
```

Controller Side :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProfileForm(Users userData)
{
    //So on submit of form in arabic culture I am gettting Date like 01/01/0001 from view side automatically.
}
```

Comment: can you post arabic date value from view side ?

Comment: `01/01/0001` is the default value for `DateTime`. Are you sure that this value is being sent in the post request?

Comment: in view side when we select any date from datetimepicker then it's showing perfect date but when we submit then on controller side it's changing.

Comment: @phuzi when culture is english then it's showing correct datetime but when it's arabic culture then it's not showing correct date. both culture using same datetime entity.

Comment: @Hardik What value does the field have in the content of the POST request from the browser?